# Error calling web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap

I'm trying to call a web service from my Android app. I deployed a web service that inserts a record (product barcode, product name) with Hibernate in Java and I wrote an activity to test it.

When I run it on my AVD I got a connectionException : `Connection refused`

Here is my code:

```
package com.market_helper.app;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class Market_helper_androidActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://localhost:7675/market_helper/services/Main";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "insertProduct";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost:7675/market_helper/services/";
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:7675/market_helper/services/Main?wsdl";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
           request.addProperty("barCode", "12345");

           request.addProperty("productName", "abc");
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object result = envelope.getResponse();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It's my first webservice on Android and I'm not sure if the code is right. I'm calling a method that called `insertProduct(String barCode,String productName)`. The web service is working and tested.

Comment: Connection refused points to the most obvious answer - localhost:7675 is not listening.

Comment: instead of Localhost use the ip address of the webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://localhost:7675/market_helper/services/Main";
```

You have given LocalHost

try with ip address instead of LocalHost

lik this

```
   private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://10.120.159.87:7675/market_helper/services/Main";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml be sure you have Internet permissions set, I was having the same issue once I set this everything worked great.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String URL = "http://localhost:7675/market_helper/services/Main?wsdl";
```

in this line it is wrong to put "?wsdl" at the end of the URL remove it and put extension(.asmx or .svc) of ur webservice at the end instead of it.Like...

```
private static final String URL = "http://localhost:7675/market_helper/services/Main.asmx";
```

Comment: I'll try to fix this thank you all .I think that i should use an alias to  apache tomcat server because the phone will confuse about the host .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me I have fixed my problem with
the url 
I used the ipconfig command to get my local ip
the port 7675 is used by my apache tomcat server 
I added the port to my firewall exception port to be sure that it works .

and there is no asmx file I changed ?wsdl 
now I can see the wsdl description from my browser.

I have got the namespace is from the xml file "main.wsdl"

`<schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://app.market_helper.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`


the correct code is here :
    `private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://app.market_helper.com/insertProduct";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "insertProduct";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://app.market_helper.com";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.2:7675/market_helper/services/Main?wsdl";`
now I can use the web service now from my Android app .
I send back my correct code for people who have the same problem as me .

Answer (score 0):

I can see when I open explorer. I use this website

> "http:// local host:49674/Service.svc"

What should I write? I always get error in try catch. I used WCF in .net webservice. and EntityFramework.

> ```
>      private final String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/IService/";
>      private final String SOAPACTION="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetTreatmentValues";
>      private final String METHODNAME="GetTreatmentValues";    
>     private final String URL="http:// local host:49674/Service.svc";
> ```

where is my error ?
(Also I use ksoap 2.4)

Answer (score -1):

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://localhost:7675/market_helper/services/insertProduct"; 

SOAP ACTION=NAMESPACE+METHOD NAME;
```